# Linq to XML giving no values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I just can't seem to figure out whats wrong with this code... Any idea's what I'm doing wrong. The select returns one item, with all null attributes, i.e the foreach loop gets entered once and the WMServer Server.[pick attribute] is set to null.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"pathtoxmlfile.xml");
var wms = from e2 in xdoc.Elements("GISImportConfig").Elements("BaseMapLayers")
          select new
          {
              Url = (string)e2.Attribute("url"),
              Enabled = (string)e2.Attribute("enabled"),
              UserName = (string)e2.Attribute("username"),
              Pasword = (string)e2.Attribute("password"),
              Layers = e2.Elements("WMLayer")
          };

foreach (var Config in wms)
{
    WMServer server = new WMServer();
    server.ServerURL = Config.Url;
    server.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(Config.Enabled);
    server.UserName = Config.UserName;
    server.Password = Config.Pasword;

    foreach (var layers in Config.Layers)
    {
        WMLayer layer = new WMLayer();
        layer.Group = (string)layers.Attribute("group");
        layer.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(layers.Attribute("enabled"));
        layer.Name = (string)layers.Attribute("name");
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<GISImportConfig OracleServer="*" OracleInstance="*"   OracleSchema="*">
  <BaseMapLayers>
    <WMServer  url="https://example" enabled="true" username="someuser" password="somepass">
      <WMLayer name="0" enabled ="true" group="test"></WMLayer>
      <WMLayer name="1" enabled ="true" group="test"></WMLayer>
    </WMServer>
    <WMServer url="server2" enabled="false" username="" password="">
      <WMLayer name="test2" enabled ="true" group="test"></WMLayer>
    </WMServer>
  </BaseMapLayers>
</GISImportConfig>
```

Comment: `Select` can't change the count of elements of the original source, that means you have to look at the source...

Comment: I think you've got an extra `</WMLayer>` in that `xml` (not related to the problem).

Comment: Thanks, wasn't in the source xml file. I've edited the question.

Comment: @will I can see your xml file **has only 1** `BaseMapLayers` element, so how could you expect it to have more than 1?

Comment: I was looking to get information on the WMS server elements (two of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get only one result, because you have only one `<BaseMapLayers>` element, and that's the one you're looking for with your query. Add `.Elements("WMServer")` method call and it should work:

```
from e2 in xdoc.Elements("GISImportConfig").Elements("BaseMapLayers").Elements("WMServer")
select new
{
    Url = (string)e2.Attribute("url"),
    Enabled = (string)e2.Attribute("enabled"),
    UserName = (string)e2.Attribute("username"),
    Pasword = (string)e2.Attribute("password"),
    Layers = e2.Elements("WMLayer")
};
```

Returns 2 elements with non-null attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the `WMServer` elements and you're currently selecting the `BaseMapLayers` element (of which only one exists).

You could get the `WMServer` elements by doing this:

```
from e2 in xdoc.Descendants("WMServer")
select new
{
      Url = (string)e2.Attribute("url"),
      Enabled = (string)e2.Attribute("enabled"),
      UserName = (string)e2.Attribute("username"),
      Pasword = (string)e2.Attribute("password"),
      Layers = e2.Elements("WMLayer")
};
```

which will grab you all the `WMServer` descendent elements.

I think MarcinJuraszek has a better answer (appending the relevant element), as there's less scope to run into problems if you find a misplaced `WMServer` element, or only want those at that specific location in the xml.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how your answer differed from MarcinJuraszek. It helped.